# Does anyone know how to create and save a png image of a winform to a png file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've created a form using Visual Studio 2010, using C#.  I want to create and save a png picture of it (Form1.cs[design]).

Comment: Programmatically or manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a screenshot using the "Print key". Then copy the result into a program like Paint and click save. Save it as .png and you're done.

To sum the key combinations (Thanks to chris):

1. <kbd>Print</kbd> to take a picture of the whole screen
2. <kbd>Alt + Print</kbd> to screenshot the active window
3. <kbd>[WinKey http://pixelmonster.org/pool/windows_key_coloured.png](http://pixelmonster.org/pool/windows_key_coloured.png) + Print</kbd> to make a screenshot and save it directly to %USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Screenshots\xxxx.png and gets automatically numbered (only working with Windows 8)

You can also use the [Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool) (just run `SnippingTool` from the Run dialog in Windows) which was firstly integrated in Windows Vista.

If you want to make this programatically you can use
[Control.DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) method.

Comment: ALT + Print Screen gives you just the window that has focus, if you don't want to do all the cropping in Paint.

Comment: @chris.nesbit1 Holy crap how did I not know that! Thanks!

Comment: thanks chris, forgot about this! +1

Comment: great answer- thanks @Pixelmonter / chris.nesbit1

Comment: i'll sound like a fool here but how do you press windows? I don't see a windows key.

Comment: @chris.nesbit1 Never knew of that, looks like I don't need to use snippet as much anymore!

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as best answer to close this question.

Comment: sorry- I've only just started using stack overflow properly even though I've been registed for over a year @Pixelmonster

Answer (score 1):

Use Control.DrawToBitmap Method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(Width,Height)) 
{
DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\screenshot.png");
}
```

Comment: How does this take a screenshot?

Comment: I thought he want to do it Programmatically. He didn't responded to that question.

Comment: You are right, the question is very confusing with the Visual Studio and C# Tag.